# Why is it OK to commute a quantum operator with the cross product?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, parity

I am going through lecture notes relating to the parity operator $\mathcal{P}$

My confusion relates to the derivation of the symmetry transformation of the orbital angular momentum

$$\mathcal{P} \vec{L} \mathcal{P}^{\dagger} = \mathcal{P} (\hat{\vec{x}} \times \hat{ \vec{p}})\mathcal{P}^{\dagger} = (\mathcal{P} \hat{\vec{x}} \mathcal{P}^{\dagger}) \times (\mathcal{P} \hat{\vec{p}}\mathcal{P}^{\dagger}) = (- \hat{\vec{x}} \times (-\hat{\vec{p}})) = + \vec{L}$$

For the second equality, the professor inserted $\mathcal{P}^{\dagger}\mathcal{P}$ using the fact the operator is hermitian, $\mathcal{P} \mathcal{P}^{\dagger} = \mathbb{I}$. The explanation he gave for being allowed to place the operators on either side of the cross product, as I understand it, is : the cross product is an operation on the components of $\hat{\vec{x}}$ and $\hat{ \vec{p}}$ and does not act on objects which live in Hilbert space (while the operators live in Hilbert space).

Is this a sufficient explanation ? Since a matrix representation can be given for $\mathcal{P}$, and due to the similarities of the cross product and matrix multiplication, I am still a bit uneasy commuting the two.

I am in general a bit timid when it comes to commuting two objects. Is the fact the two objects live in different spaces a good argument to use to justify commuting them ?

Comment: tried writing it down in components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works because  the cross product is simply a special set of products of operators.. It helps to remember that the "operator" $\vec{L}$ is actually three separate operators $L_x$, $L_y$, and $L_z$.

For example, $L_x = \hat{y}\hat{p}_z - \hat{z}\hat{p}_y$ so
\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}L_x\mathcal{P}^† 
& = \mathcal{P}\hat{y}\hat{p}_z\mathcal{P}^† - \mathcal{P}^†\hat{z}\hat{p}_y\mathcal{P}^†
\\ &  = \mathcal{P}\hat{y}\mathbb{I}\hat{p}_z\mathcal{P}^† - \mathcal{P}\hat{z}\mathbb{I}\hat{p}_y\mathcal{P}^†
\\ &  = (\mathcal{P}\hat{y}\mathcal{P}^†)(\mathcal{P}\hat{p}_z\mathcal{P}^†) - (\mathcal{P}\hat{z}\mathcal{P}^†)(\mathcal{P}\hat{p}_y\mathcal{P}^†)
\\ & = (-\hat{y})(-\hat{p}_z) - (-\hat{z})(-\hat{p}_y)
\\ & =  \hat{y}\hat{p}_z - \hat{z}\hat{p}_y = L_x
\end{align}

The same thing happens for $L_y$ and $L_z$, so we say $\mathcal{P}\vec{L}\mathcal{P}^† = \vec{L}$.

Note that this didn't involve the commutation relationship between the position operators and the momentum operators. It also didn't have to do with commutation between $\mathcal{P}$ and the other operators. The $\mathcal{P}^†\mathcal{P}$ that shows up in between $y$ and $p_z$ in the third line above gets there because it's equal to the identity operator, not because those operators commute.

Comment: Thank you, as you said in the first line thinking of the cross product as a set of products of operators made it very clear to me. So using your third equality and letting P be any hermitian operator and $\vec{L}$ any cross product of operators, $\mathcal{P} \vec{L} \mathcal{P}^{\dagger} = \mathcal{P} \hat{\vec{x}} \mathcal{P}^{\dagger} \times \mathcal{P} \hat{\vec{L}} \mathcal{P}^{\dagger}$

Answer (score 2):

*I am in general a bit timid when it comes to commuting two objects.* Good!

In this instance it is fine. I will use Einstein notation: let $(\hat V_1)_i$, $(\hat V_2)_i$ be two operator-valued vectors on Hilbert space, so for each value of $i$ $(\hat V_1)_i$ is some operator on Hilbert space. Let also $M_k^{ij}$ be a tensor of numerical coefficients.

Therefore we can use the linearity of $\mathcal P$ and its conjugate to pull the tensor $M$ inside:
$$
\mathcal P M_k^{ij} (\hat V_1)_i (\hat V_2)_j\mathcal P^\dagger= M_k^{ij} \mathcal P  (\hat V_1)_i (\hat V_2)_j\mathcal P^\dagger=M_k^{ij} \mathcal P  (\hat V_1)_i \mathcal P^\dagger \mathcal P(\hat V_2)_j\mathcal P^\dagger\,.
$$

For your application $V_1$ and $V_2$ will be the position and momentum operators, $i=1,2,3$, and $M$ will specify the cross product. (This involves the Levi-Civita antisymmetric symbol.)

Comment: Thank you the generality of the proof is very helpful. It makes it clear the operator acts on the components of the operator-valued vector, and not on the vector which was my initial confusion. If I understand correctly, we have a double sum where each $M^{ij}_{k}$ is just a number. Linearity of the operator P gives $P(cf) = cP(f)$ where c is a constant and f is a function. This is equivalent to saying P commutes with numbers. Can I ask what the index k is indicating ?

Comment: @MrLolo: all correct. $k$ for this example enumerates the components of the vector $\vec{x}\times \vec{p}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you write it out componentwise you see that non-commuting products like $x_ip_i$ never appear.   In $\hat L_x$ for instance you have $yp_z-zp_y$.  If you then think of $p_z\to -i\hbar \partial_z$ etc it’s clear this commutes with $y$.  You can then use the parity operator in the normal way on the product.